# Apply the notifyDataSetChanged on stored list in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a problem about my listview i am populating my listview with what the user enters in the dialog box when the add new button is clicked. When this button is clicked a dialog appears and asks the user to input something when the user presses done what he/she enters does not appear in the view from the list even when i put the notifyDataSetChanged. What the user inputs only appear when the fragment has been restarted.  I think it may involved the saving in sharedpreferences which is the tinyDB in the code. How do i make sure the notifyDataSetChanged is noticed by the list that is stored. Thank you

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_year_two_my_courses_first_semester, container, false);
    btnAddNew = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewYearTwoFirstSemester);
    btnSave = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveAddedSubjectsFirstSemesterYr2);
    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewSubjectsMyCoursesFirstSemesterYr2);
    tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext());
    storedList = new ArrayList<>(tinyDB.getListString("storedList1stYr2"));
    storedArray = new ArrayList<>();
    generalList = new ArrayList<>();

    generalList.addAll(storedArray);
    generalList.addAll(storedList);



    getActivity().setTitle("Year Two");

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),R.style.DialogeTheme);
            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Add new");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            String getUsername = tinyDB.getString("Username");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Hello "+ getUsername + ", please write the new subject");
            final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f06292"));
            alertDialog.setView(input);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String getSubjectInput = input.getText().toString();
                    storedList.add(getSubjectInput);
                    tinyDB.putListString("storedList1stYr2", storedList);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
    arrayAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getContext(),generalList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CustomListAdapter is observing generalList, which does not change when you add a new String in storedList.

You could do this :

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String getSubjectInput = input.getText().toString();
                storedList.add(getSubjectInput);
                tinyDB.putListString("storedList1stYr2", storedList);

                generalList.add(getSubjectInput);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

or clear and reset your list.